# Xcode cocoa - dynamically change the checkbox bool

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I want to write test_application for MacOS which will show whether IM client is running. This test_application also will have ability to start and kill IM Messenger (checkbox on/off)

I understand how to run / kill application with the help of push-buttons and now i want to show status of IM (is it running or not) and show checkbox ON or OFF depending on it

I suppose, i need to use some system call like "ps -aux processname" and parse it or use some API from Cocoa - but i can't understand how to get that information to test_application and how to do it outside any method (i want test_application to load initial information at it start, so if i open test_application it looks whether IM Messenger is running and makes checkbox ON or OFF without any clicks)

Comment: The title for this question is a bit misleading, as it appears that you are wanting to dynamically change checkbox BOOL value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a look at `GetBSDProcessList` and the [Process Manager Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/Process_Manager/Reference/reference.html) to get running processes and daemons.

You could also use [`NSAppleScript`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAppleScript_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and some AppleScript to launch the application or [`NSTask`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/Reference/Reference.html) along with `ps -aux processname` and `grep`

Comment: Thanks. Now the question is how to modify checkbox bool due to result of ps / nstask / applescript